# getting count based on sum of values in other columns SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

```
 PID  |  ChildPID | value
------|-----------|-------
 3835 |   3934    |  1
 3835 |   3935    |  0
 3835 |   3936    |  0
 3835 |   3939    |  1
 3836 |   3940    |  0
 3836 |   3941    |  0
 3836 |   3942    |  0
```

and i need results like

```
PIDCountinvalue|  Childcountinvalue | PIDCountoutvalue|  Childcountoutvalue 
---------------|--------------------|-----------------|-------------------|
 1             |   2                |  1              |      5
```

means i need get count of PID,ChildPID based on sum of value corresponding those and if child Id belongs to one PID having complete values as **0** then only PID will get count in   **PIDCountoutvalue** column or else if it's having **>0** after summing up all ChildPID of that PID i will be considered as **PIDCountinvalue**, and coming to Childcount in/out it's just based on corresponding values.

explanation:

```
 PIDCountinvalue|  Childcountinvalue | PIDCountoutvalue|  Childcountoutvalue 
 ---------------|--------------------|-----------------|-------------------|
  1(3835)       |   2 (3934,3939)    | 1 (3836) |5(3935,3936,3940,3941,3942)
```

there are total two PID: (3835,3836) and PID:3835 having 4 childids (3934,3935,3936,3939) (sum of values of childs > 0) and PID:3836 having 4 childids (3940,3941,3942) (sum of values of childs = 0), so if you sum the values of childIds under there respective PId's if that sum of the value count=0 then that corresponding PID will count as **PIDCountoutvalue** else it wil come under **PIDCountinvalue** like that 3836 is in outvalue count and 3835 is in value count.

Comment: I don't follow the logic which led to your expected output.  Maybe you can be a bit clearer about how you are summing things here.

Comment: can you check the explanation....@Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Your explanations are not very clear and I cannot catch your logic, but here's an example code that can help you. You can easily modify it to fit your needs.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([PID] varchar(6), [ChildPID] varchar(11), [value] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([PID], [ChildPID], [value])
VALUES
    ('3835', '3934', '1'),
    ('3835', '3935', '0'),
    ('3835', '3936', '0'),
    ('3835', '3939', '1'),
    ('3836', '3940', '0'),
    ('3836', '3941', '0'),
    ('3836', '3942', '0')
;

--You can use a common table expression to "build" a table and then to query what you need.
with 
cte as
(
    select PID, ChildPID, sum(value) [Sum]
    from Table1 
    group by PID, ChildPID
)

--Now just build you columns with the aggregated data you need.
select 
     (select 
        count(distinct PID) 
        from cte 
        where [Sum] > 0)        as PIDCountinvalue    --Get count of PIDs with sum of values more than 0
    ,(select 
        count(ChildPID) 
        from cte 
        where [Sum] > 0)        as Childcountinvalue  --Get count of ChildPIDs that have values larger than 0
    ,(select sum(I.PIDs) from
        (select
            count(PID) PIDs
            from cte 
            group by PID
            having sum([Sum]) <= 0) I)  as PIDCountoutvalue   --Get count of PIDs with sum of value less than 0
    ,(select 
        count(ChildPID) 
        from cte 
        where [Sum] <= 0)       as Childcountoutvalue --Get count of ChildPIDs that have values less than 0
```

The output of that query is exactly what you've wanted. However, since your logic is not clear to me, this may not be the final solution for your complete data. But I hope it helps at least a bit.